# Замыкания в foreach и for

Tags: c#

Почему при добавлении анонимных методов в делегат в цикле **foreach**, переменная i не замыкается и происходит вывод не последнего элемента массива 4 раза, а всех?

```
//D объявлен как delegate void D()
D func = Console.WriteLine;

foreach(var i in new [] { 1,2,3,4 })
{
    func += () => Console.WriteLine(i);
}
func();
```

При этом, если переписать ту же операцию под цикл **for**

```
//D объявлен как delegate void D()
D func = Console.WriteLine;

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    func += () => Console.WriteLine(i);
}
func();
```

То все ожидаемо - четверка выводится 4 раза

Comment: в какой версии пробовалось?

Comment: [Замыкания на переменных цикла в C# 5](https://habr.com/ru/post/141270/)

Comment: @tym32167, я точно помню уже был подобный вопрос, только найти не могу :)

Comment: @Grundy, Пробовал в .net 3.5 и .net 4.8 ответ на вопрос искал, но ответа не нашел

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо tym32167
Цитата из статьи на Хабре - [Замыкания на переменных цикла в C# 5](https://habr.com/ru/post/141270/):

> В C# 5.0 решили изменить цикл foreach таким образом, чтобы на каждой итерации цикла переменная i создавалась вновь. По сути, в предыдущих версиях языка C# в цикле foreach была лишь одна переменная цикла, а начиная с C# 5.0, используется новая переменная для каждой итерации

Answer (score 0):

Потому что так и задумано: в современном C# на каждой итерации создаётся новая переменная, специально чтобы не было проблем с замыканиями.